# Add script in Item context menu

Tags: powershell

I would like to add `PowerShell script` on the home item context menu. I have added in `Script library` by creating a `Content Editor` followed by a `Context menu` folder. However, it is not showing the script in the home item context item. I have added the `show rule` and `enable rule`.[image]

Comment: did you try this - https://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/05/27/launch-powershell-scripts-in-the-item-context-menu-using-sitecore-powershell-extensions?

Comment: Yes , I have tried this and I have created Content editor and context menu item manually. Is it create any issue ?

Comment: no, we created the same way, please try IISReset and then see

Comment: I have tried to reset IIS  and it is not showing in context menu.

Comment: What do your rules look like? https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/content-editor

Comment: To enable script on particular template and show script on particular folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly follow this link :-

https://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/05/27/launch-powershell-scripts-in-the-item-context-menu-using-sitecore-powershell-extensions/

If it is still not showing in `Context menu` then Kindly check your parent folder template. If it is created by the below template

```
`/sitecore/templates/Modules/PowerShell Console/PowerShell Script Module`
```

then try to select checkbox in `Module Activation` tab.

[image]

I am using Sitecore SXA.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved the issue.